# grails create-ng-controller foo" gives 'Error Command not found create-ng-controller'

Tags: grails, grails3

I created todo app with [angular  profile](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/webServices.html#angularProfile) with grails3

```
grails create-app -profile angular -features hibernate5,json-views todo
cd todo/server
```

Versions (I am on cygwin+windows)

```
Grails Version: 3.2.9
$npm --version
    3.3.4
$node --version
    v6.9.4
```

Error I get is

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: TieredCompilation is disabled in this release.
| Error Command not found create-ng-controller
Did you mean: create-controller or create-restful-controller or generate-controller?
```

All pre-requisites are on command line. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Grails made some changes to its profile names. Old "angular" profile became "angularjs. Angular 2 based work came under new "angular" profile.   The change was introduced as part minor version - 3.2.9